# how do you invoke functions with if statements?

Tags: javascript

```js
function calculator(a, b, operation) {
  
  if (addNum()) {
  var result = addNum(); // 4
    console.log("the result is " + result);
  } if (subsNum()) {
   result = subsNum(); // 2
     console.log("the result is " + result);
  } if (multNum()) {
     result = multNum(); // 6
     console.log("the result is " + result);
  } if (divNum()) {
     result = divNum(); // 1
     console.log("the result is " + result);
  }

}

function addNum(a, b) {
  return 2 + 2;
// return  a + b;  //why not?
}

function subsNum(a, b) {
  return 4 - 2;
   // return a - b;
}

function multNum(a, b) {
  return 2 * 3;
     // return a * b;
}

function divNum(a, b) {
   return 8 / 8;
    // return a / b;
}


  calculator();
```

Create a function addNumbers that takes 2 parameters and returns the sum of those parameters.

Create a function subtractNumbers that takes 2 parameters and returns the difference of those parameters.

Create a function multiplyNumbers that takes 2 parameters and returns the product of those parameters.

Create a function divideNumbers that takes 2 parameters and returns the quotient of those parameters.

Create a function calculator that takes 3 parameters. The first two parameters are the numbers. The third parameter, called operation, is the operation you will execute.

- If the operation is “addition”, you should execute the function addNumbers.
- If the operation is “subtraction”, you should execute the function subtractNumbers.
- If the operation is “multiplication”, you should execute the function multiplyNumbers.
- If the operation is “division”, you should execute the function divideNumbers.

How do you replace integers with arguments( in `addNum()` function for example to add a + b instead 2 + 2) and then how do you replace those arguments when you call the `calculator()` function with whatever integer you want? Is it possible to do it like this `calculator(addNum(2,5));` ? if the `addNum(a,b )` return a + b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you replace integers with arguments( in `addNum()` function for
>   example to add a + b instead 2 + 2)

As you have stated, you can use arguments. Arguments will allow you to pass in variables into your function so that it can use them.
Eg:

```
function addNum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

So, now that `addNum` takes 2 values (as there are two parameters `a` and `b`), you must *pass* through two numbers when calling your function:

`addNum(5, 2);` <--- This will return (not print) the value of 5 (`a`) plus (`+`) 2 (`b`), so 7

This is how you use arguments.

> How do you replace those arguments when you call the `calculator()`
>   function with whatever integer you want?

If `calculator()` has 3 parameters, `a`, `b` and `operation`, this means that within the calculator function `a` represents the first number, `b` represents the second number and `operation` represents the math operator. All of these variables will have values when the function is executed and ran. Thus, in your calculator, you can check what the `operation` is equal to using `if` statements (eg: if `operation == "addition"`, then call the `addNum` function with the two numbers `a` and `b` (so we would do `addNum(a, b)` to add the two numbers together)). You can apply this logic to your other operations.

> Is it possible to do it like this calculator(addNum(2,5)); ? if the
>   addNum(a,b ) return a + b?

While this is entirely possible, you would have to rewrite your `calculator` function. Moreover, this is not following the specifications you've given.  At the moment, with the code you've provided, you cannot do this as your `calculator` function takes 3 arguments:

`a` - The first number

`b` - The second number

`operation` - The operator which tells us whether we will add (`addition`), subtract (`subtraction`), etc...

Thus, when you call your `calculator()` function, you must *pass* through these 3 arguments. Doing `calculator(addNum(2,5));` will not achieve this as `addNum(2, 5)` will evaluate to 7, so this would be equivalent to writing `calculator(7)`, which doesn't make sense as you're only passing in one argument in this case.

So, in order to properly use the `calculator` function, you need to pass through 3 values (arguments) like so:

`calculator(2, 5, "addition")`

This will tell the calculator function to add the two numbers (2 and 5) together (due to the `operation` being "addition"). However, in order for this to work, you firstly must edit the insides of your calculator function to adapt the logic of testing what the `operation` is to correctly decide on what function to call.

Comment: I read your comment and it makes sense. Thank you very much for your input. Much love to you ! I also modified a little bit my code and you can see it here: https://codepen.io/konstantin0s/pen/gQvJQY?editors=1111

Comment: Also, I've modified your code very slightly. Instead of doing a `console.log()` in your calculator function (as all you want your calculator to do is do the calculations (not the displaying of the result)) you can instead get the returned result (ie the answer) when you call the `calculator()` function, and then display the result using a `console.log()`. Take a look at the codepen for a better idea https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EOQBGB?editors=1111

Comment: thank you, now it looks even better ! :) You are the best, Nick

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to invoke this with if statement as it will complicate things.

> Is it possible to do it like this calculator(addNum(2,5)); ? if the addNum(a,b ) return a + b?

This is possible and you should do it that way. Basically you are passing a function to your calculator function. So, it will work like -> `calculator function` takes `operation` argument which contains another function (`addNum`, `subsNum` etc) and executes it.

```
function calculator(operation) {
  return operation
}

function addNum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
// return  a + b;  //why not?
}

function subsNum(a, b) {
  return a - b;
   // return a - b;
}

function multNum(a, b) {
  return a * b;
     // return a * b;
}

function divNum(a, b) {
   return a / b;
    // return a / b;
}

console.log(calculator(addNum(2,3)));
// returns 5
```

There is also room for improving the code and repetition. But that is another story.

Comment: While this would log result, `calculation` function is just an useless wrapper here, you could call `console.log(addNum(2,3))` as well

Comment: You are absolutely right, that is why I mentioned about the improving the code. My example was made to re-assure op that it is possible to pass a function as an argument, which op asked for.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a function calculator that takes 3 parameters. The first two
>   parameters are the numbers. The third parameter, called operation, is
>   the operation you will execute.

I suggest to create a flag where you can choose which function to execute.
For example:

```
//function call    
calculator(2,5,'addition'); 

// function method
calculator(a,b,flag){
 switch(flag) {
     case 'addition': addNum(a,b);
        break;
        ...
}}
```

Comment: Hello Krissy, Thank you for your input. I managed to fix the code but I am repeating console.log at each case and in javascript is that rule, DRY(don't repeat yourself).